# Volume of a solid of rotation with respect to $y$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The problem gives the equation of a curve and some boundaries and asks to find the volume of the solid formed when rotating around various axes. The equation is $y=\sqrt{x}$. The boundaries are $y=0$ and $x=3$. The shape formed is approximately a right triangle with a slightly convex hypotneuse. The problem asks to find the volume when revolving around the $y$ axis.

I know that the washer method is needed and I believe the outer radius $= 3$ and the inner radius is equal to the equation of the curve, but because there is a horizontal rotation I believe that means the equation must be rewritten in terms of $y$, so that would be $f(y)=y^2$.

I solved the problem as follows: $$\begin{align*}
V&=\pi \int_0^2 \left[(3)^2-(y^2)^2\right] \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&=\pi \int_0^2 \left[9-y^4\right] \, \mathrm{d}y\\
&= \pi \left( 9y-\frac{y^5}{5} \bigg|_0^2 \right) \\
&=\pi \left[18 - \frac{32}{5} \right] \\
&=\frac{58\pi}{5} \end{align*}$$

However the correct answer is $V=36\pi \sqrt{3}/5$.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, for the most part, your setup is correct. However, you should not be integrating over $0$ to $2$ as you have, but the entire ranges of $y$ values the shape lies in.

That is, from $y=0$ to $y=\sqrt 3$: the function $f$ "peaks" at the right boundary of the shape, and $f(3) = \sqrt 3$:

[image]

Fixing the bounds will give you the correct answer (as [Wolfram confirms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi+integral+from+0+to+sqrt%283%29+of+%289+-+y%5E4%29+dy)).